# How to configure a server using Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I am very new to Chef and trying to use it for configuring a server for the first time. I want to run the following commands on a remote server using chef solo.

```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip    
   sudo apt-get install gcc    
   sudo pip install scrapy    
   sudo apt-get install python-dev    
   sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev    
   sudo pip install scrapy    
   sudo pip install storm    
   sudo apt-get install MySQLdb    
   sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

And then copy my python code to a ~/project directory on the server. Can anyone please help me with how to go about it.
I have downloaded the cookbooks for python, apt and build-essentials.
I am reading the documentation but not able to tie everything together on how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

so `chef-solo` is a command line tool that has to be ran when SSHed to the remote host as I understand it. I know of no way to run it remotely. Running it remotely is more the aims of `chef-client` and `chef-server`

Basically you have two different things. You need to install some system packages and some python packages.

I would look for community recipes to install those system packages, but most of them are trivial so they might not exist.

I don't think there is a resource for python packages.( http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources )

So you will probably have to fake it with bash.

so here is what you need to do.

Make a cookbook for each system package to be installed

Make a cookbook for (optionally each) python thing you care about (that depends on the appropriate system libraries

Aggregate the above cookbooks into a role

your system library cookbooks will look pretty boring like

--
cookbooks/python-imaging/default.rb

```
include_recipe "python-imaging::install"
```

--

cookbooks/python-imaging/install.rb

```
case node["platform"]
when "ubuntu", "debian"
package "python-imaging"
else
raise "Unsupported platform #{node["platform"]}"
end
```

--

then make a role that looks like

```
{
"run_list": [
"recipe[python-imaging]",
"recipe[another-cookbook]"
]
}
```